# How do I transform Corpus content to vector after newline "\n"

Tags: r, tm, strsplit

When I try to use strsplit on plain text, it has the desired property that the value stored is transformed from a string of characters to a vector with strings of characters. For example,

```
txt = "The fox is Brown.\nThe Fox has a tail."
strsplit(txt, "\n")
```

For the actual problem I'm using the NLP package, **tm** (v0.7-1) in R 3.4.0 on Windows 7.

When I create my corpus and try to use the **content_transformer** function in **tm**, it breaks my corpus up instead of returning a vector of the content.

```
require(tm) #version 0.7-1
txt = "The fox is Brown.\nThe Fox has a tail."
docs = Corpus(VectorSource(txt))
to_newline = content_transformer(function (x) unlist(strsplit(x, "\n")))
docs = tm_map(docs, to_newline)
str(docs)
```

The output from `str(docs)`  in the code above looks like:

```
List of 2 
 $ 1:List of 2 
  ..$ content: chr "The fox is Brown." 
  ..$ meta   :List of 7
  .. ..$ author       : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ datetimestamp: POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2017-06-25 15:11:55"
  .. ..$ description  : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ heading      : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ id           : chr "1"
  .. ..$ language     : chr "en"
  .. ..$ origin       : chr(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "TextDocumentMeta"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "PlainTextDocument" "TextDocument"
 $ 2:List of 2
  ..$ content: chr "The Fox has a tail."
  ..$ meta   :List of 7
  .. ..$ author       : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ datetimestamp: POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2017-06-25 15:11:55"
  .. ..$ description  : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ heading      : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ id           : chr "2"
  .. ..$ language     : chr "en"
  .. ..$ origin       : chr(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "TextDocumentMeta"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "PlainTextDocument" "TextDocument"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "SimpleCorpus" "Corpus"
```

I want it to look like the following where `$ content` is a vector of characters:

```
List of 1 
 $ 1:List of 2 
  ..$ content: chr [1:2] "The fox is Brown." "The Fox has a tail." 
  ..$ meta   :List of 7
  .. ..$ author       : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ datetimestamp: POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2017-06-25 15:11:55"
  .. ..$ description  : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ heading      : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ id           : chr "1"
  .. ..$ language     : chr "en"
  .. ..$ origin       : chr(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "TextDocumentMeta"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "PlainTextDocument" "TextDocument"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took a lot of trial and error. In fact, I was using `DirSource` in order to read in a corpus of data and all I needed to do was convert the function sequence reading in the corpus to say `VCorpus(DirSource(directory_name), ...)`.

In order to demonstrate the problem create a text file:

```
The fox is Brown.
The Fox has a tail.
```

Save the file in your working directory in a folder named `test` and save the file as `test.txt`.

Then run:

```
docs = VCorpus(DirSource("./test"))
str(docs)
```

Notice how the `content` is not a character vector!!!